# Como identificar a versão do MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, assembly

Como posso identificar a versão MVC que estou usando no meu projeto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Com seu projeto aberto, Expanda `References`.
2. Clique com botão direito sobre `System.Web.Mvc`.
3. Clique em `Properties`.
4. Verifique a versão em `Version`, conforme mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pergunta adicionada ao SOpt como fonte de pesquisa com base [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930217/which-version-of-mvc-am-i-using) do SO.

Answer (score 7):

Como não foi especificado se é em código ou não, vai pelo código:

```
typeof (Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/GetVersion.cs).

Comment: Bacana bigown, será muito útil também!!